# Dialog box that selects a worksheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro that will duplicate a worksheet from one workbook into a worksheet in another workbook. Is there a way I can use VBA code to allow me to manually select which worksheet I shall be duplicating?

Right now the macro works, as long as I have the full worksheet name typed into the actual VBA code. Ideally, I'd like the macro to allow me to select the worksheet through a dialog box. I know you can just copy/paste the sheet or its contents, but the guys I'm working for don't want to do that, due to the size.

Comment: You can also select worksheets by index.

Comment: What have you tried so far to tackle this problem. SO helps in solving coding problems. You can certainly break this total operations in parts and for some of the sub parts you can easily get the code from various questions put here.

Comment: If you want to `"...select the worksheet through a dialog box."` then you should start by creating that dialog box. Since I am unaware of any such dialog box that ships by default with Excel, I'd say that you'll have to create it yourself using a `UserForm` and a `ListBox` inside that form.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Worksheets` collection to populate the `ListBox` in a user form. This should get you started:

[image]

Code *in the user form (!)*:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim v As Worksheet

    For Each v In Worksheets
        UserForm1.lstWorksheets.AddItem v.Name
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub cmdSelectWorksheet_Click()
    MsgBox "You selected " & lstWorksheets.Value
End Sub
```